# Failing to convert JPG to PDF with GhostScript

Tags: windows, pdf, jpeg, ghostscript

I'm trying to apply a recipe shared in other posts, but it fails for a reason I can't understand:

```
c:\tmp>gswin64c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o output.pdf "c:\Program Files\gs\gs9.50\lib\viewjpeg.ps" -c "(input.jpg) viewJPEG"
GPL Ghostscript 9.50 (2019-10-15)
Copyright (C) 2019 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Error: /invalidfileaccess in --file--
Operand stack:
   (input.jpg)   (r)
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:730/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:78/200(L)--   --dict:8/20(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Permission denied
GPL Ghostscript 9.50: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ghostscript (as of version 9.28) defaults to SAFER being active.

Try adding the `-dNOSAFER` parameter just like this:

```
>gswin64c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o output.pdf -dNOSAFER "c:\Program Files\gs\gs9.50\lib/viewjpeg.ps" -c (input.jpg) viewJPEG
```

Have a look at [Ghostscript's command line options](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Options)
for further reference.

(You might want to check [-dSAFER](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Safer) and [-dNOSAFER](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#NoSafer) in particular)

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :) I added a couple direct link to Ghostscript SAFER/NOSAFER options for your convenience